# How to set fixed position the react native action button on the screen

Tags: react-native

Can I set the position of react native action button to fixed on a flat list?
I have added an action button but when I scroll the flat list, the action button hides!

Thanks, advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to use the [`Animated`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/animated) API

First you need to create a Flatlist that you can animate. This is easily done with `Animated.createAnimatedComponent()`:

```
import { Flatlist, Animated } from 'react-native'

const AnimatedFlatlist = Animated.createAnimatedComponent(Flatlist)
```

Now in your parent component `constructor` create a new `Animated.Value`. This will be the value you use to animate your component to scroll along with your `AnimatedFlatlist`:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props)
  this.state = { translateY: new Animated.Value(0)}
}
```

Then wrap the component you want to be fixed in an `Animated.View` and make sure you add a [`transform`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/transforms) to the component style, passing it the animated value you created :

```
<Animated.View style={{ transform: [{ translateY: this.state.translateY }]}}>
  {YourFixedComponent}
</Animated.View>
```

Finally, you need to attach an `Animated.event` to your `AnimatedFlatlist`. This is done using the `onScroll` prop:

```
<AnimatedFlatlist
  data={...}
  renderItem={...}
  keyExtractor={...}

  onScroll={Animated.event(
    [{nativeEvent: {contentOffset: {y: this.state.translateY}}}],
    {useNativeDriver: true}
  )}
  scrollEventThrottle={1}
/>
```

Now your element with move along with your Flatlist. This is a basic example, and you will probably need to mess with [`interpolation`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/animations#interpolation) and CSS positioning to get it exactly as you want it.